# JMS queue with persistence enabled - performance bottlenecks

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, messaging

This question is to try and understand performance bottlenecks, if any, that would exist in listening to a message from a queue in which messages are persisted where the JMS provider resides vs listening to a message from the same queue had the message not been persisted. All minute differences needs to be considered as the end-to-end response time starting from dequeing the message to processing the message needs to be complete in millisecond time frame.

Based on the comparison results, a decision needs to be taken whether the persistence of messages need to be forwarded to a separate queue that does not affect the mainstream consumers that need a millisecond response. Any insights into the differnces between the way messages are handled between a persistent queue vs non-persistent would also be great

Comment: Which Provider are you using?

Comment: @RichardW Im planning to use Active MQ. But the question was more provider agnostic and generic.